# Text data manipulation in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file with some data I want to clean and export as csv but the format is too messed up .
The lines in the txt file are in this format

```
Somemail@email.com:specialcode | Status - 2022-11-25

anotheremail@email.me:anothercode | Status - 2023-08-15

myemail@server.net:codeworcd | Status - 2036-06-19
```

and so one

I want to convert the lines to

```
Someemail@email.com , specialcode , Status , 2022-11-25

anotheremail@email.me, anothercode , Status , 2023-08-15 

myemail@server.net, codeworcd, Status, 2036-06-19
```

So that i can save the file as csv.

How can I approach such a complex situation? I can loop over the lines and split it with `split(‘:’)` but each character is different. So it appears more challenging.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown sample please try the following:

```
import csv, re

with open("file.txt") as fi, open("output.csv", "w") as fo:
    writer = csv.writer(fo)
    for line in fi:
        l = re.split(r':| [|-] ', line.rstrip())
        writer.writerow(l)
```

Result:

```
Somemail@email.com,specialcode,Status,2022-11-25
anotheremail@email.me,anothercode,Status,2023-08-15
myemail@server.net,codeworcd,Status,2036-06-19
```

- It assumes the input filename is "file.txt" and the output filename
  is "output.csv".
- The delimiter is defined as `:| [|-]` . It splits the line on a colon
  or a sequence of a whitespace, pipe or hyphen, and a whitespace.
  The important thing is the
  pipe character and hyphen are surrounded by whitespaces as shown in
  your sample.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it without regex

**assuming** that you have a text file in filesystem, that you are or can read
using read_csv

```
# read in the text file, and name the columns, assuming there is only one '|' in file

df=pd.read_csv(r'csv.csv', sep='|', header=None, names=['col1','col2'])

# split col1 on colon
df[['email','code']]=df['col1'].str.split(':', expand=True)

# split only one occurrence on hyphen
df[['status','date']]=df['col2'].str.split('-', 1,expand=True)

# drop the read-in columns
df=df.drop(columns=['col1','col2'])

# write to csv
df.to_csv(r'csvout.csv')
```

```
    email                 code          status  date
0   Somemail@email.com    specialcode   Status  2022-11-25
1   anotheremail@email.me anothercode   Status  2023-08-15
2   myemail@server.net    codeworcd     Status  2036-06-19
```